# Python - Removing first two occurrences of element in list

Tags: python

The objective of this function is to remove the first two occurrences of n in a list.

Below is a code I had written but I still got it wrong after many hours. A friend advised me not to edit a list while iterating. However, I'm still stuck.

```
def remove_first_two(list,n):
    if list == []:
        return []
    else:
        count = 0
        for ele in list:
            if ele == n:
                list.remove(ele)
                count += 1
                if count == 2:
                    break
    return list

list = [1,2,2,3]
print(remove_first_two(list,2)) => [1,2,3] instead of [1,3]
```

Comment: So what do you want it to do if there are fewer than 2 occurrences of `n` in your list?

Answer (score 1):

Use `list.remove` twice with try-except. That will delete first two entries. Complexity `O(n)`

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4]

try:
    list_a.remove(n)
    list_a.remove(n)
    # run a loop too, if it's more than 2
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try find all indexes and del:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,3,2,4]
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == 2]
print(indices)

[1, 3, 5]
```

```
del a[indices[0]], a[indices[1]]
print(a)

[1, 3, 2, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use 'list' as its a key word in Python. Use something else, like 'alist'.
The code below does what you want and keeps the basic form of what you already have. You can of course also use the built-in .remove() method.

```
def remove_first_two(alist, n):
    if alist == []:
        return []
    else:
        count = 0
        while count < 2:
            for ele in alist:
                if ele == n:
                    alist.remove(ele)
                    count += 1
    return alist

alist = [1,2,2,3]
print(remove_first_two(alist,2)) # Output -> [1,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

When your friend says "do not edit a list while iterating," he/she is right, and what he/she means is that you should create another list all together. What you are looking to do is the following:

```py
def remove_first_two(list, n):
    if list == []:
        return []
    else:
        new_list = []
        count = 0
        for ele in list:
            if ele == n:
                if count >= 2:
                    new_list.append(ele)

                count += 1
            else:
                new_list.append(ele)

    return new_list
```

However, note that you can use use some built in functions to make your life much easier:

[`list.remove(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

Therefore, you can more simply do:

```py
def remove_first_two(list, n):
    if list == []:
        return []

    for _ in range(2):
        if n in list:
            list.remove(n)

    return list
```

Answer (score 0):

Python updates the list if you change it while iterating.

> In you test case with `list = [1,2,2,3]` when `list[1]` is deleted and **Python updates** `list = [1,2,3]`. Now Python understands you have iterated till index 1 and continues from index 2 which now contains `3`. So Python encounters **only one occurance of 2**.

**So heed your friends advice and do not edit list while iterating** :)

> Now you can use Python's in-built `list.remove(element)` to delete first ocuurence of a element. Repeat it 2 times for desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Also O(n) with a single parse.

```
def remove_first_two(mylist,n):
    counter = 0
    def myfilter (i):
        nonlocal counter,n
        if counter > 2:
            return True
        else: 
            counter += 1
            return (i != n)
    return (list(filter(myfilter,mylist)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in python 3.8 using assignment expressions in a list comprehension:

```
data = [1,2,3,2,3,2,4]

count = 2
num = 2

[x for x in data if x != num or (count:=count-1) < 0]
```

Results:

```
[1, 3, 2, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason why your program does not work:
When you remove an element, the `for` loop moves on to the next element, but by "moving on" it is actually skipping the element which now occupies the position of the deleted element. It skips the element right after the one you deleted.

The correct way to iterate over a list while you delete elements is making index progression explicit, by using a while loop instead of a for loop, and not increase the index when you delete an element:

```
i = 0 
while i < len(my_list):
    if condition:
        my_list.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
```

However, none of this is necessary in your case! Notice that when you use `my_list.remove(ele)`, you are not providing an index as you would with `my_list.pop(i)`, so Python has to search for the first element that matches `ele`. Although `remove` will be slower than `pop` when used by themselves, here `remove` allows you not use any loops at all, simply do `my_list.remove(n)` twice!

Last touch: If your list has less than two elements matching `n`, one of the two `my_list.remove(n)` commands would return a `ValueError`. You can account for this exception, knowing that if it happens, your list is ready and requires no further action.

So the code you need is:

```
try:
    my_list.remove(n)
    my_list.remove(n)
except ValueError:
    pass
```